# Codeigniter returns empty array

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am very new to codeigniter and try to write a simple blog app:

controller: posts.php

```
class Post extends CI_Model {

    function get_posts($num=20, $start=0) {
       $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','dec')->limit(0,20);
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result_array();

        }

}
```

Model: post.php

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {
    function index() {
        $this->load->model('post');
        $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts();
        echo"<pre>";print_r($data['posts']);echo"</pre>";
    }
}
```

I have populated posts table in the database. However when I try to get results I get this instead:

```
Array
(
)
```

mysql> describe posts;

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| postID     | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| title      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| post       | text         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| date_added | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| userID     | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| active     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| slug       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+------------------
```

What's wrong with this code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your query is getting wrong as you already have `->from('posts')` so you dont need the table name any more in get

Change

```
$query = $this->db->get('posts');
```

With

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

And

```
->order_by('date_added','desc')
```

Comment: You should able to see your last query using `echo $this->db->last_query()` after $this->db->get() to make sure your query is correct

Comment: replacing db->get('posts') with db->get() did not solve the problem. however when I commented out //->order_by('date_added','dec')->limit(0,20); the array contents appered. Any ideas why it was so?

Comment: can you check the column name `date_added` is correct, i checked the query and its working for me. What you get on `echo $this->db->last_query()` after get();

Comment: i got it what your problem is `->order_by('date_added','desc')` not `-`->order_by('date_added','dec')`